# How to know if a .tflite file can run on a specific edge device in C++ before attempting inference?

Tags: c++, tensorflow-lite, tflite

I am trying to write a logic that checks to see whether an Android device is capable of runniing an inference of a given .tflite file.

How can I go about implementing a logic for device-model compatibility in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compiled your TFLite library (or used gradle dependency) for arm/arm64 then it should work on the device no need for check here.
If you're trying to use a specific delegate or different hardware then please explain it so we can help.